# Как найти parent key в multiarray по значению?

Tags: php, массивы, search

Есть массив:

```
$array['aKey']=array('a','b','c');
$array['bKey']=array('d','e','f');
$array['cKey']=array('g','h','i');
...
```

как получить первичный ключ без перебора для значения?

Например: найти ключь `bKey`, если я имею значение `f`.

Comment: есть массив... как получить первичный ключ без перебора для значения?

Comment: без перебора не получится

Comment: Нужно построить ещё 1 хэш, только по значениям ( типа такого`['a'=>'aKey','b'=>'aKey', ..., 'i'=>'cKey']` ).